# Calculating a field in modelbuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, field-calculator

I am trying to update attributes in a table using Calculate Field in Model Builder. I have used the following bit of code but its not updating the field.

```
    expression:
    Change(!Zone!)

    def Change(Zone):
      if (Zone == "NULL"):
      return "Non UK"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to indent the last line as such:

```
expression:
Change(!Zone!)
```

```py
def Change(Zone):
  if (Zone == "NULL"):
    return "Non UK"
```

BUT what if Zone is not null? I assume you want to return it's value? Thus the code should be:

```
expression:
Change(!Zone!)
```

```py
def Change(Zone):
  if (Zone == "NULL"):
    return "Non UK"
  else:
    return Zone
```

Comment: For some reason, that doesn't work. All the <null> values are still the same. The tool works in model builder, but the attributes are not updated.

Comment: Are well now you are saying something completely different which is <Null> and not the string "NULL". You will want to replace if (Zone == "NULL") with if Zone is None:

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    def Change(Zone):
        if not(Zone):
           return "Non UK"
```